# Hadoop cluster. Large number of TCP retransmissions

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, tez

We have hadoop2 cluster including 2 namenodes, 13 datanodes and 1 'mediator' machine with DB for meta. Namenodes and datanodes are in the same data center, but meta DB is on remote side.

When executing MR jobs there are a lot of TCP retransmissions and TCP packets duplicates between all nodes.

Is it normal behavior at all?